# How to show error in common component in lightning web component - LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am developing an app on Lightning web component which has several child components and few nested components as well. I don't want to show error on toast.

So if any component's has any error it would be shown up in error component.

My question is what would be the best way if I want errot to be shown on common component? Please see attached image.
[image]

In this case it we will have to use pubsub. But what are drawbacks of pubsub in this case?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you not want to use a toast here? Any specific reason? While pub sub will work here but that could be just an overhead here.

Comment: @JayantDas it is a application specific requirement. Apparently it is clear that pubsub will add overhead here but what other options are? I have one in mind that error portion should not be a component instead it should be part of parent component/app. What do you think?